# How to clean buildSrc dir from root project in Gradle?

Tags: build, gradle, multi-project

I have ***multiproject*** build in the **buildSrc** dir.

```
  buildSrc
       ---build
       ---  subProject1
          ----build (2)
       ---  subProject2
           ----build (3)
       ---  subProject3
          ----build  (4)
       ---  subProject4
          ----build  (5)
    config
    gradle
    src
    build (1)
```

When I am in the root dir of my project I write:

```
gradle clean
```

but only **build** dir of the root project was deleted(marked with 1). How to trigger *Gradle* to delete all build directories prom **buildSrc** without to go manually to **buildSrc** and to write `gradle clean`.(marked with 2,3,4,5)

Comment: What version  of `gradle` do you use?
Do you have `settings.gradle` in you root dir, where you `include` all your subprojects to the root project?

Comment: Gradle 2.0. Yes I have settings.gradle and in the build script I have
runtime subprojects.collect { owner.project(it.path) }. Because my buildSrc project is multi-project build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this (but you shouldn't ever have to clean `buildSrc`).

Comment: I do not understand why?

Comment: Because `buildSrc` is a separate and implicit build that finishes before even the configuration phase of the main build starts.

Comment: Ok but Gradle can clean it automatically or with some system property cleanBuildSrc =true to specify the intention of the user this can be done or I am wrong.

Comment: Always cleaning `buildSrc` is possible, but doesn't make sense. I'm not aware of any way to clean `buildSrc` depending on what system property etc. is passed on the command line. Instead, I'd focus on eliminating the need to ever clean `buildSrc` (it shouldn't ever be needed).

Comment: Gradle does not consider results dirty when you modify a `build.gradle` even though the rigorous thing to do is consider all results dirty. This is a time that you may wish to clean.

Comment: When there is a big in your compiler and your buildSrc build head an error after updating to a compiler with a fix it would be very very nice to have buildSrc build invalidated

Answer (score 18):

Since `buildSrc` is just a gradle project, you can start gradle in `buildSrc` folder with `clean` task specified using `-p` gradle option:

```
./gradlew -p buildSrc clean
```

Unfortunately it still requires another gradle invocation before your main build.

Comment: This does not seem to actually clean `buildSrc`.

Comment: @KennKnowles It cleans the build results of the `buildSrc` project, not the entire `buildSrc` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The meta-build output is right there:

```
rm -rf buildSrc/build
```